# Ruby Routes issue on first app (Mac). - Newbie warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I've gone through the installs and it seems to work correctly.  I can get to the default home page and spin up the server, but once I generate a couple of things and update the routes.rb file, I can't get the server to run after updating routes.
Here is the top of routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

# set the index page / root url
  root ‘pages#home’

  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/home'
```

Here is what I get (I'd guess I'm missing something obvious) when running the server:

```
Mymachine:myrubyblog2 emusic$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/emusic/Sites/myrubyblog2/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `‘pages' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fb85e2c2b80> (NameError)
```

This is what I get on a Generate:

```
:myrubyblog emusic$ rails generate controller home index
/Users/emusic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load': /Users/emusic/Sites/myrubyblog/config/routes.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
```

I've checked formatting every way I can imaging and can't see what is wrong.

Comment: It looks like you have back-tics ` instead of quotes '' around `root 'pages#home'` If you copy and pasted that try just typing it on a new line.

Comment: Do you have `end` after `pages/home` in your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: That looks to be it.  I'm using textedit and it seems to be converting my tics to a different character.  Can't seem to turn the behavior off.  Probably not the editor I should be using.  Thanks for the feedback.  I starred at this for hours yesterday wondering why it didn't work.  and I do have an 'end' at the very bottom of the routes.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your error:

```
/Users/emusic/Sites/myrubyblog2/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `‘pages' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fb85e2c2b80> (NameError)
```

it appears your root is written wrong here:

```
root ‘pages#home’
```

Try `root 'pages#home'` instead.

Also note that you can then hash out or remove `get 'pages/home'`

Try reading through this to get a better understanding:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html section **4.3**

Have you tried migrating your database prior to launch: `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:reset`?

Comment: Thanks as well.  I've consumed every tutorial I can find.  No DB migration yet.